# Current Host Server for Availability Groups

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, clustering

We have a 4 Node multi Subnet Availability Group. When i go to the Cluster Manager I could see the Current host server is the Node 4  whereas the AG Primary node is Node 1. Will the AG go down if Node 4 goes down ?

Please advice whether is this a normal behavior and will there be in any problem if i move all the cluster resources to the primary node during production.

Comment: What is the sync status for AG ? is Node 4 set to sync and automatic failover ? Can you post a screen shot ?

Comment: Node 1 and Node 2 - Synchronous with Automatic Failover, Node3 and Node 4 Asynchronous Mode and Node 4 is on a different subnet

Comment: I already answered this in another question and your comment. Closing as duplicate.